# Why can the parameter in this predicate be omitted?

Tags: scala, function, parameters

I just stumbled over this line in the play2-auth samples:

```
val remember = request.tags.get("rememberme").exists("true" ==) || //...
```

I understand what it does (check whether the map tags contains the mapping `"rememberme" -> "true"`), however I found the predicate in `exists()` interesting and have never seen one written in this way.

After testing this a bit in the REPL I came to the conclusion that it has the same meaning as

```
.exists("true" == _)
// or even longer:
.exists(s => "true" == s)
```

This notation apparently also works with other single argument functions, not just predicates:

```
scala> Some("world").map("Hello " +)
res0: Option[String] = Some(Hello world)
```

Why can the parameter here be omitted? Ultimately it seems to save one character, the underscore. It seems a bit odd to me to introduce a language feature just for that. Is there some bigger picture related to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be omitted because methods are automatically converted to functions.  One could say that one would only do that for methods on objects or which were imported into scope, so you don't need to specify the object they're on.  But it's more consistent just to say: if you name a method, and a function is called for, the compiler will convert it for you.

So, `"Hello ".+` names a method (technically, the `$plus` extension method from `StringOps`).  And thus it gets converted to a function.

As to why automatic conversion is allowed at all instead of always requiring a `_`, well, that's more subjective.  If you're using a more functional style, you use it a lot, so it's nice not to have the superfluous `_`s littering the place when you know very well what you mean (e.g. `xs.foreach(println)`).

Comment: Subjective: moreover, the rule used to be broader, and was changed to convert only if the expected type is a function. Otherwise, it is converted to "empty application", `f()`.